# jQuery.ajax success callback not called although Pyramid did return response

Tags: python, jquery, pyramid

I have this simple jQuery ajax post to a Pyramid webapp.

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'http://localhost:6543/test',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: JSON.stringify({"username":"demo","email":"demo@something.com","Password":"1234"}),
     success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
     },
     error: function (msg) {
         alert("error");
     }
});
```

Pyramid Route:

```
config.add_route('test', 'test')
config.add_view('tagzu.views.test', route_name='test', renderer='json')
```

Pyramid view:

```
def test(request):
    return {'content':'Hello!'}
```

now when I call the service, I am sending this

Request:

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:6543
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 66
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"username":"demo","email":"demo@something.com","Password":"1234"}
```

and I get this reponse:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: PasteWSGIServer/0.5 Python/2.7.1
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 01:42:33 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 21

{"content": "Hello!"}
```

### Problem is:

the ajax success handler is never been called.
Only the error handler keeps firing with an error
msg.statusText = 'error'

Please let me know what if I am missing something.
thanks

Comment: Can you try dataType: 'html'? So we'll see if it has nothing to do with datatype.

Comment: I tried html and text and without any dataType all together. Still the same problem. thanks

Comment: From the HTTP response you get, I really don't see why your success callback never gets called. Where did you get the response text? Is it really what your browser get? Also, you could try `console.log(msg);` in your error callback and inspect the content of the object in Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For however is encountering the same issue as me, ie. not having enough sleep!!

For the sake of God make sure the html is on the same server, as this happens because of calling across domains of course, the html with jQuery is just a local file, the service is served on localhost.

So the server was rejecting the query without any error details to point me in the right direction.

Cross-domain was the last thing I would have thought of, being too focused on Pyramid, I thought it might be doing something funny. 
Funny me, for wasting so much time.